# If $\lim_{t\to +\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x)\exp(e^{xt}) \, dx=0$ then $f=0$ a.e?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration, analytic-functions

> **Question,** Let $f \in L^1(\alpha, \beta)$ , $\beta>0$ and
> $$
> F(x)= \int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(t)\exp(e^{xt}) \, dt
> $$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to +\infty}F(x)=0$. Does this imply that $f$ is identically zero almost everywhere?

[A similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545772/if-lim-t-to-infty-int-0-pi-fxext-dx-0-then-f-0?noredirect=1#comment9562736_4545772) posed by myself was answered using Phragmén-Lindelöf, but the difficulty here stems from the extremely fast growth of $\exp(\exp(z))$ along the positive real axis.
This I why I think we can't use the Phragmén–Lindelöf principle.